# Titanium and google cloud messaging

Tags: android, notifications, titanium, push

I'm trying to implement push notifications in my app.

I'm reading the titanium documentation and it says that I need to use Titanium.CloudPush and ACS.

The documentation states the need for an production api key, development api key, and api key.
I see a development and production app key in the configuration page for acs apps, I'm guessing this are the production and development api keys... right?

Which key should I use for the generic api key??

Answer (score 0):

Renato, Your guess is correct. The development api key and production api keys are the same you found on Appcelerator Site. You can also see the same in your tiapp.xml file. But the API key that you need to provide to implement server push in Android, should be generated by you. Follow the steps below, taken from [developer site](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)

**To create a Google API project:**

1. Open the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com).
2. If you haven't created an API project yet, click Create Project.
3. Supply a project name and click Create.

   Once the project has been created, a page appears that displays your **project ID and project number**.
   *Copy down your **project number**. You need to use it on the **Appcelerator Site as GCM sender ID** of your application.*

**To enable the GCM service:**

1. In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth.
2. In the displayed list of APIs, turn the Google Cloud Messaging for Android toggle to ON.

**To obtain an API key:**

1. In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth > Credentials.
2. Under Public API access, click Create new key.
3. In the Create a new key dialog, click Server key.
   In the resulting configuration dialog, supply your server's IP address(if any) or leave it blank(I haven't provided the server ip and left it blank in my projects).
4. Click Create.
5. In the refreshed page, copy the **API key**. *This is what we use in the **Appcelerator Site as API Key**.*

You may refer [this link](http://www.titaniumtutorial.com/2013/10/acs-push-notification-using-gcm.html) also. Since the blog contains detailed reference how to setup GCM in Titanium for Android.

I hope this helped you. Feel free to ask if you have any queries :)